# Нужна ли запятая между тремя глаголами разного времени?

Tags: пунктуация, запятые, глаголы, и

В части предложения **"была, есть(,) и будет"** нужна ли указанная запятая?

Answer (score 2):

Однородные члены предложения обычно отвечают на один и тот же вопрос, но со сказуемыми это правило не действует. Иными словами, однородные сказуемые могут быть выражены глаголами разного времени, разного вида (или даже одно сказуемое может быть именным, а другое — глагольным. *Она молода, изящна, любит жизнь* (Чехов)).
[Однородные главные члены предложения](http://www.hi-edu.ru/e-books/xbook089/01/part-029.htm)

*Любовь всегда была, есть и будет,

это мы блуждаем в поисках своих...*
А. Ильин-Медведев

*Земля амурская была, есть и будет русской* (надпись на арке в Благовещенске).
*Ничто не вечно, кроме музыки. Она всегда была, есть и будет* (Д. Ловато).
*Кубань всегда была, есть и будет опорой великой России* (В. Кондратьев).

Запятая перед союзом **и** не нужна — он соединяет однородные сказуемые, которые относятся к одному и тому же подлежащему.